# Can't receive incoming connection to local IP

Tags: connection

I'm using windows 7, and I can't see to connect to a localhost at another PC(A) that's in the same local area network. Usually, I'd enter the IP address in the browser and it works but now I can't seem to connect.

However, from that other PC(A), I can browse to other IPs in the network. Basically I'm able to have outgoing connection but can't receive connection to this PC. Not sure what else to do.

Does anyone know a work around to this?

Thanks.

-Hakimo

Answer (score 0):

How is the Firewall configured? If it is blocking the port you are using for incoming connections then the listening application will never see the connection.

The default is to allow outgoing connections (i.e. have to explicitly block ports), but for incoming the default is to block.